Why are duplicated column names in data.table with by=.EACHI not fixed?
This is a follow-up question to How does the data.table `on` logic work for unequal joins? . However I will state everything needed here again, so there is no need to read the linked question in order to understand the question(s) here.
I want to compute the rolling median for every entry: For every time stamp it shall take all past entries not older than 10 seconds and compute the median. Here is one way you can do that:
dt <- data.table(time = as.POSIXct("2020-06-01") + c(13, 20, 23, 26, 30, 38, 42, 50),
                 x = c(0, .1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000))

dt[,time10 := time - 10]
dt[dt, on = .(time <= time, time >= time10)][,.(xmed10 = median(x)), time]

or alternatively using
dt[dt, on = .(time >= time10, time <= time), .(xmed10 = median(x)), by = .EACHI][,time := NULL][]

See the answer by jblood94 in the linked question for more details.
While investigating the second approach I realized that in the intermediate result dt[dt, on = .(time >= time10, time <= time), .(xmed10 = median(x)), by = .EACHI] there is a duplicated column name which I find confusing. Why is it not fixed like when not using by = .EACHI?
Have a look at this:
dt <- data.table(time = c(13, 20, 23, 26, 30, 38, 42, 50),
                 x = c(0, .1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000))

dt[,time10 := time - 10]
dt[dt, on = .(time <= time, time >= time10)]

You can see that the second "time" is changed to "time.1"
    time     x time10 time.1   i.x
 1:   13 0e+00      3      3 0e+00
 2:   20 0e+00      3     10 1e-01
 3:   20 1e-01     10     10 1e-01
 4:   23 0e+00      3     13 1e+00
 5:   23 1e-01     10     13 1e+00
 6:   23 1e+00     13     13 1e+00
 7:   26 1e-01     10     16 1e+01
 8:   26 1e+00     13     16 1e+01
 9:   26 1e+01     16     16 1e+01
10:   30 1e-01     10     20 1e+02
11:   30 1e+00     13     20 1e+02
12:   30 1e+01     16     20 1e+02
13:   30 1e+02     20     20 1e+02
14:   38 1e+02     20     28 1e+03
15:   38 1e+03     28     28 1e+03
16:   42 1e+03     28     32 1e+04
17:   42 1e+04     32     32 1e+04
18:   50 1e+04     32     40 1e+05
19:   50 1e+05     40     40 1e+05

However here this is not the case:
dt[dt, on = .(time >= time10, time <= time), .N,by = .EACHI]

gives duplicated names:
   time time N
1:    3   13 1
2:   10   20 2
3:   13   23 3
4:   16   26 3
5:   20   30 4
6:   28   38 2
7:   32   42 2
8:   40   50 2

My first question is: Why is this not fixed?
Now I am confused how to distinguish between those two column both called "time" and I do not understand how to access them. It seems that time in the j-argument of the [.data.table is a vector of length 1, but the TIME is a vector of different length. Maybe somebody can explain in more detail what is happening here:
> dt <- data.table(time = c(13, 20, 23, 26, 30, 38, 42, 50), x = c(0, .1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000))
> dt[,time10 := time - 10]
> dt[,TIME := time]
> dt[dt, on = .(time <= time, time >= time10), .N,by = .EACHI]
   time time N
1:   13    3 1
2:   20   10 2
3:   23   13 3
4:   26   16 3
5:   30   20 4
6:   38   28 2
7:   42   32 2
8:   50   40 2
> dt[dt, on = .(time >= time10, time <= time), .N,by = .EACHI]
   time time N
1:    3   13 1
2:   10   20 2
3:   13   23 3
4:   16   26 3
5:   20   30 4
6:   28   38 2
7:   32   42 2
8:   40   50 2
> dt[dt, on = .(time <= time, time >= time10), .(.N, collapsed_TIME = paste(TIME, collapse = ", "), collapsed_time = paste(time, collapse = ", ")),by = .EACHI]
   time time N collapsed_TIME collapsed_time
1:   13    3 1             13             13
2:   20   10 2         13, 20             13
3:   23   13 3     13, 20, 23             13
4:   26   16 3     20, 23, 26             20
5:   30   20 4 20, 23, 26, 30             20
6:   38   28 2         30, 38             30
7:   42   32 2         38, 42             38
8:   50   40 2         42, 50             42
> dt[dt, on = .(time >= time10, time <= time), .(.N, collapsed_TIME = paste(TIME, collapse = ", "), collapsed_time = paste(time, collapse = ", ")),by = .EACHI]
   time time N collapsed_TIME collapsed_time
1:    3   13 1             13             13
2:   10   20 2         13, 20             13
3:   13   23 3     13, 20, 23             13
4:   16   26 3     20, 23, 26             20
5:   20   30 4 20, 23, 26, 30             20
6:   28   38 2         30, 38             30
7:   32   42 2         38, 42             38
8:   40   50 2         42, 50             42

To me it seams that the first "time" column in the result comes from the first entry in the on = .( , ) - vector whereas the second "time" looks at the second entry in the on = .( , ) - vector. The "time" columns are constructed in a way that is explained in this picture:

If however, you use time in the j-argument of [.data.table, then it is a vector of length 1 and the order of the on = .( , ) - vector does not matter.
So my second question is: What are the mechanisms behind all of that?
My third question is: Is there anywhere a good documentation?

Normally you want to have one question in a post. Maybe pick the one you most want answered? :)

In case there is a good answer to my third question, this would be the most wanted, otherwise the second :-)

It seems you have successfully teased out most of the detailed behavior of data.table non-equi self-joins. If you were to ask me, "Is this behavior desirable?" and "Is this behavior what the package creators intended?", I would say "no" and "probably not all of it". You may consider submitting an issue.
